# what does it mean "Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode" in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-props

I am trying to loops through these array's but am getting this error "Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode"

```js
const myList =[
    {
        id: 01,
        title: 'FrontEnd Engineer',
        name : 'Sheshathri',
        describtion: "simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
    },
    {
        id: 02,
        title: 'QA Engineer',
        name : 'Jobin',
        describtion: "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }
  ]
  
  export default myList;
```

In App.js

```js
import myList from './ContentList';

const listItem = myList.map(list => <Content key= {list.id} title = {list.title} name = {list.name} describtion = {list.describtion} />);
```

Comment: strict mode by default throws error for legacy methods/code, you should avoid legacy code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am trying to loops through these array's but am getting this error
> "Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode"

It refers to yours ids:

```
id: 01,
title: 'FrontEnd Engineer',
```

Replace with

```
id: 1,
title: 'FrontEnd Engineer',
```

> Octal literals are numerals that begin with a leading zero, such as:
>
> var num = 071;      // 57
>
> The leading zero to identify an octal literal has been a source of
> confusion and error in JavaScript. ECMAScript 5 deprecates the use of
> octal numeric literals in JavaScript and octal literals cause syntax
> errors in strict mode.

[Octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) system